# How to remove the separator for only one section in a static UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static

I'm implementing a static TableView which has two sections in Swift. I want to have the same effect as `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None` in only section 0, while remaining the separator in the other section. Since it is a static TableView, I cannot configure the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function (which always get a cell value `nil`). I tried to make some IBOutlet for each of the static cells and configure their `seperatorInset` and `layoutMargins` property, however it just doesn't work. So I would like to know if there are other ways to remove the separators? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to set it up using tableview Separator. As you said its a static tableview, so simple way to do it is just Remove the Separator from the tableview and add the Separator UIComponent at the bottom which looks like a Separator for the required cells.

Here is the screenshot for that as well[image]

Comment: Thought the solution looks not elegant enough, however it works fine... Thanks a lot!
It seems that static tableviews are not that usable...

Answer (score 7):

First add effect UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None To the tableView. After that you can add a small view in your cell Which looks like the separator.
Then give the connection to the separator View with the cell.after that the only thing you have to do in the cellForRowAtIndexPath is

```
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
     seperatorView.hidden = false
} else {
     seperatorView.hidden = true
}
```

This is a small trick to solve your Problem. Hope it helps

Comment: I found this solution earlier, however i cannot use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to configure cells in a static tableView... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @chakshu's answer, in `GetCell`(Xamarin.iOS):

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var customCell = TableView.DequeueReusableCell(SomeCellId, indexPath) as SomeCustomCell;
    if ( customCell == null )
        return null;

    var view = new UIView();
    var bounds = customCell.Bounds;
    view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
    view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(bounds.X, bounds.Height - 1, bounds.Width, 1);
    customCell.Add(view);

    return customCell;
}
```

Comment: If you want the standard separator color, you could use `view.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(new CGColor(200 / 255f, 199 / 255f, 204 / 255f));` instead. Or you could also consider `view.BackgroundColor = TableView.BackgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

1.First set your tableViewSeparatorInset to zero:

```
tableView.separatorInset = .zero
```

2.Doing validate where the separatorCell will appear in "**cellForRowAt**", for example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: DeliveryCell.self, for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == .deliverySection {
       cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(horizontal: tableView.bounds.width, vertical: 0)
    }
}
```